# Wordpress roots/sage theme template single page for CPT

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using roots/sage theme template for wordpress for a project.
I have a CPT named "tour" and want to create a single page for it. I see in the files provided by sage a single.php that looks like this:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/content-single', get_post_type()); ?>
```

I go take a peak in the content-single page and see this:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header>
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); ?>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <?php wp_link_pages(['before' => '<nav class="page-nav"><p>' . __('Pages:', 'sage'), 'after' => '</p></nav>']); ?>
    </footer>
    <?php comments_template('/templates/comments.php'); ?>
  </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm thinking okay this is just an example so I remove everything from the content-single.php and place a `<h1>hello</h1>`

I go take a look at my CPT single page and get an error "page not found"
anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Archive pages will load templates/content-cpt.php
Single pages will load templates/content-single-cpt.php

Where "cpt" is your custom post type name ("tour" here ).So create 
templates/content-tour.php and templates/content-single-tour.php and that will work .

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the WordPress template hierarchy.

> Custom Post Types use the following path to render the appropriate
>   archive index page.
>
> 1. archive-{post_type}.php
> 2. archive.php
> 3. index.php

If your custom post type is public, you'll be able to access the posts by visiting {your-url}/{custom-post-type-slug}

Comment: Hey Josh, side question: do you add thise template (following the main question) archive-tour.php inside the templates folder? or place it in the root of the template directory?

Comment: In the root of the directory, templates is for your own partials that do not subscribe to the default WordPress template hierarchy. Although I believe the plan is to change this in the Sage 9 release.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reaction. I am doing it this way: I copy the template-custom.php file and rename it accordingly to what I need. then I create a new file in the templates folder. Too bad there isn;t a best practise guide!

Answer (score 0):

After you set up a post type you should also go to Settings > Permalinks in the the WordPress back-end and press Save Changes. This seems to update the system so that the new post type's slug works.